# Getting error 400 OpenAI files endpoint Node.js

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I have been trying for hours, tried CSV data, JSON data, tried it all I keep getting either a 415 error or a 400 error; if I can have any help that would be great, the documentation and the AI itself has not been at all helpful in trying to inject data to train a model

Text:

```
This is a text file for the OpenAI API.
It contains sample data for testing purposes.
Here is another line.
And another.
```

Code:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream('./myfile.txt'), {
  filename: 'myfile.txt'
});

axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/files', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + API_KEY
  }
})
.then(response => {
  // Handle response
})
.catch(err => {
  // Handle error
  console.log(err)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files/upload), you are missing the required `purpose` field...

> #### Request body
>
> **`file`** *Required*
> ...
> **`purpose`** *Required*
>
> The intended purpose of the uploaded documents.
>
> Use "fine-tune" for Fine-tuning. This allows us to validate the format of the uploaded file.

```js
const FormData = require("form-data");
const fs = require("fs");

const API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("purpose", "search"); //  adjust accordingly
formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream("./myfile.txt"), "myfile.txt");

axios
  .post("https://api.openai.com/v1/files", formData, {
    headers: {
      ...formData.getHeaders(), // this is simpler
      authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // Handle response
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err.response?.data, err.toJSON());
  });
```

Comment: Sadly I am still getting the 400 error, any other ideas why?

Comment: What does the response data look like (ie what do you see from `console.log(err.response?.data, err.toJSON())`)?

Comment: It was because they needed it in JSONL only, although the docs say you can do it differently, it doesnt work unless its JSONL